# remove particular lines from a file

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I have a a file like:

```
NBU82
-------
PBW99
-------
PBE84
-------
PBW110
APSW1474
-------
TSMTBL
CTTRBAPCTRK01
WEBED0075
-------
PBW132
-------
```

I want to remove the ones which are empty (without any value after port)
i.e just want to print

```
PBW110
APSW1474
-------
TSMTBL
CTTRBAPCTRK01
EBED0075
```

Answer (score 2):

awk would be easier:

```
 awk -v RS="---*" -v ORS="-------" 'NF>=2' file
```

output:

```
PBW110
APSW1474
-------
TSMTBL
CTTRBAPCTRK01
WEBED0075
-------
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible `sed` command that generates output identical to Kent's:

```
sed ':a;N;/-$/!ba;/^[[:alnum:]]\+\n-/d' file
```